# PhoneGap sockets-for-cordova quit app

Tags: ios, cordova, sockets, phonegap-plugins

I have a PhoneGap application and I want to open a socket to a endpoint using `sockets-for-cordova` plugin:

```
var socket = new Socket();

socket.open(
    "192.168.2.1",
    80,
    function () {
        // invoked after successful opening of socket
        console.log("connection");
        $scope.$apply();
    },
    function (errorMessage) {
        // invoked after unsuccessful opening of socket
        console.log("error");
        $scope.$apply();
        socket.shutdownWrite();
    });
```

After I use this function to handle messages

```
socket.onData = function (data) {
    // received message
}
```

On Android it works well, sending and receiving message, unfortunately on iOS it simply doesn't work, not receive any message at all or it close the socket itself.

I can see "connection" message, so I guess that the socket is created.